# How to use jquery API over html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

context: I have an ajax request which return data structure with an html key.

I would like to wrap this data with a jQuery object to be able to use API like width / height and modify the data before adding it to the DOM.

```
> $('<div width="220" height="200"></div>').width()
0
```

So how could I do to get 220 and then modify it ?

I'm using jquery 1.7.2

Edit:

I'm not from the 90's because I use the wrong tag in my example. My need is to change width and height of an iframe for responsive:

```
> $('<iframe width="220" height="200"></iframe>').width()
0
```

Comment: can't you just append it into some hidden element like hidden iframe, then manipulate whatever you want, after that delete that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements have no width before they're added to the DOM.

A solution, if you really need to not have it in the DOM, is to add it and then detach it :

```
var d = $('<div width="220" height="200"></div>');
d.appendTo(document.body);
var w = d.width();
d.detach();
```

As the screen isn't redrawn until your script ends its task, this operation won't be seen by the user.

But note that without a different style, this won't give you 220. You probably want this :

```
$('<div style="width:220px;height:200px;"></div>');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/BNFHY/)

Answer (score 1):

1. You must be from the 90's, because who uses `width` and `height` attributes on a `div`?
2. There's no width "before adding it to the DOM".

3.

```
$('<div width="220" height="200"></div>').attr('width')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `css`:

`$('<div></div>').css({ 'width': '220px', 'height': '200px'});`

This will set the width and height. Since you are setting it, there really is no need to get the width afterwards, right? But you could if needed with `width()`.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I misunderstood - the question isn't too clear. If you want to get the width of an element then `width` works, but as mentioned, the element needs to be added to the DOM first.